# Lua why is 'require' unsafe to use in a sandbox environment?

Tags: lua

Via this page: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes require is marked as unsafe and it's because:

- modifies globals (e.g. package.loaded)
- provides access to environments outside the sandbox
- and accesses the file system

Pretty much all pure Lua libraries use 'require' so not having this be safe is a huge pain because you can't use any pure Lua libraries. I don't understand these unsafe reasons. It loads other Lua files in a library. Why is that unsafe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Require loads and executes code in the global environment.

For example, lets create a simple sandbox (Lua >= 5.2):

```
-- example.lua
my_global = 42

local sandbox
do
  local _ENV = { require = require, print = print }

  function sandbox()
    print('<sandbox> my_global =', my_global)
    require 'example_module'
  end
end

print('<global> my_global =', my_global)
sandbox()
print('<global> my_global =', my_global)
```

Now, lets create a module that changes `my_global`:

```
-- example_module.lua
print('<module> my_global =', my_global)
my_global = nil
```

The expectation is that inside the sandbox the only functions available are `require` and `print`. Code inside the sandbox should not be able to access the global `my_global`.

Run the example and you will see:

```
$ lua example.lua
<global> my_global =    42      -- The global environment, Ok.
<sandbox> my_global =   nil     -- Inside the sandbox, Ok.
<module> my_global =    42      -- Inside the sandbox, but loaded with require. Whoops, we have access to the global environment.
<global> my_global =    nil     -- The module changed the value and it is reflected in the global environment.
```

The module has broken out of the sandbox.

Comment: OK, so it breaks the idea of a sandbox mode in the strictest sense, but it's not as if something malicious can really be done to the persons PC if they were to run this right?

Comment: Suppose you want to restrict access to `os` functions. You load user code in a sandbox expecting that its safe, then that code loads a module that has `os.execute 'rm -rf /'` in it.

Comment: OK, so if you don't restrict os functions from a C perspective then require modules can run things. From what I see there are 2 ways of restriction. You can give a new interpreter exe where you've restricted what is available from the C Lua source OR you can try restricting what's available from a Lua file itself. if you restrict from the C source and the interpreter they are using is your own exe where you've locked it down then that would be considered your sandbox mode and can't be worked around compared to just trying to sandbox from Lua only with the default interpreter.

Comment: Sure, or you can implement a require like function to expose in your sandbox that uses [load](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) which will respect the environment.

Answer (score 3):

Since it has access to the file system and the global environment, it can execute code and modify values it's not supposed to modify.

You can implement and make available your own `require` method that satisfies your sandbox requirements. For example, you can preload those libraries you verified and have "require" only return preloaded results.

Comment: How does require allow execution of code that modifies values it's not supposed to? Can you give an example of how it can be used maliciously? I only know require to load other lua files that are still restricted by the sandbox so I can't think of how this can used incorrectly.

Comment: I was thinking about `bar.lua` doing something like `package.loaded.foo = {whatever}`, thus modifying the result of next `require"foo"` call.